# Is there a way to refer to the value of another key in the same association?

Tags: associations, slot, key

I have an association like below and want to know how to properly phrase the value for winner. in this example, the answer should be "a".

````
votes = {"a","b","c","a","a","b"}

<|
  "votes" -> votes,  
  "winner" -> TakeLargest[Counts[self["votes"]]]
|>
```
````

Comment: Will votes change after the association is created? If not, then just pre-compute it. E.g. `"winner" -> Max[Counts[votes]]`

Comment: Sorry, I was getting confused by your TakeLargest. I get that you want the "a" not the 3.

Comment: Maybe something like `<|"votes" -> votes, "winner" -> Commonest[votes]|>`

Comment: If the association is mutable, then I'd recommend creating a different data structure.

Comment: @lericr Actually, your approach worked. I precalculated it.  Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [AssociationReference](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AssociationReference/).